# Is there any differences in usage between intensifiers like molto, estremamente, and addirittura?

Tags: word-usage, difference

I have a list of intensifiers that I use:

- molto
- proprio
- veramente
- estremamente
- davvero
- addirittura

(Are there any mistakes in the list?)

It's boring to always say 'molto'. So, I like to use different words from this list at different times.

Can I use the above words interchangeably? Or are there uses I'm not aware of?

Comment: *Interchangeably* might be overstating the case. They are all intensifiers and they mean more or less the same thing, but they often carry connotations that are not always equal. For example *addirittura* has a shade of incredulity, while *proprio* has a subtle hint of precision (as in, this is really like that, I'm not confusing stuff).

Comment: they are NOT  interchangeably, although they may be sometimes. What do you mean by _intensifiers_?

Comment: @Mario It's like _really_ in _my feet are really cold_. An intensifier is an adverb used to give emphasis or force.

Comment: John, have you checked these different words on a (monolingual, if possible) dictionary, for starters?

Comment: @DaG - I have checked them in a bilingual dictionary. They all seem to share the property of being able to replace 'molto'.

Comment: @mario - I made up the word 'intensifier'. By that I simple mean a word that can be used quasi-synonymously with the word 'very', to increase the strength or intensity of what's being said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, italian here, i'll try to be the most straight and easy as I can.

- **molto** just means *very much* and it is used also as a pronoun, you can answer just with *molto* to make the other understand that you agree with what he just said.
  You can also use it just like *lot of*, or as *much*.

  > Per innaffiare serve molta acqua
- **proprio** is very different by molto and it is, to make it simple, kinda like an intensifier of what you say near to it. You can also put it with molto, like *proprio molto*, wich means *really a lot*.

  To say you are right, but with more incisiveness, you could use *proprio*

  > Hai proprio ragione
- **veramente** is basically like *proprio*, but it's closer to *actually* in english, and is **not** like *molto*. It is used to say proverbial answers like *Really?*
  Another usage of *veramente* is when you are not sure of what you heard, because it is strange or not credible. Somebody tells you that exists a man 260 years old, you can answer:

  > Ma veramente 250 anni?
- **estremamente** is barely used as sostitution of *molto* because it means *at the edge*. Composed by *estrema = edge* and *mente = basical ending of italian adverbs*.
   It is also used as *absolutely*. 
  Let's say that you put down a perfect argument, someone could answer you

  > Questo ragionamento è estremamente corretto
- **davvero** is again an intensifier and is barely used as sostitution of *molto*, it's main usage is basically the same of *veramente*.
  As *veramente* it can be used to prove the veracity of an argument.
   Same example of before: somebody tells you that exists a man 260 yars old, you could answer:

  > Davvero?
- **addirittura** is absolutely different, it is kinda like *perfino* but it's usage is pretty much restricted to answers which also tend to express a negative hopinion of the speaker. When someone answers you with *addirittura* it means that he also thinks that you've gone too far from what was needed. 

  I'll try to make it simple: 
  your mother asks you to buy two bottles of milk, so you go out and you take them, but you forget how much milk you have to take and you do take five of them. When you will be back home, your italian mother will look badly at you while saying:

  > Ne hai comprate cinque? **Addirittura**!

Comment: Some of the opinions expressed here are quite personal (just like the English they are expressed in). For instance, while it is true that the first meaning of *veramente* and *davvero* is “really”, they *are* also used as a near-synonym of *molto* in such sentences as “*Sono veramente/davvero felice di vederti*”, while their uses in questions are beyond the point of this question.

Comment: @DaG _Sono veramente/davvero felice di vederti_ isn't the same as _molto_. 
Indeed their meaning is: _I am truly happy to see you_, while _molto_ would be _I am very happy to see you_.

Comment: I am glad you explain me my own language, snailer. As I already wrote, the literal meaning is “truly”, but since nobody say *Sono felice per finta di vederti*, that use of *davvero/veramente* is to strengthen the adjective it is appended to.

Answer (score 3):

The adverbs that you listed are not exactly equivalents, even if they can all be used as intensifiers, as you say.

*Molto* and *estremamente*, together with *tanto, assai, oltremodo, sommamente, straordinariamente and quanto mai* have more or less the same meaning, and form with the adjective the "superlativo assoluto".
They are the preferred way to give emphasis or force to the meaning of the adjective.

*Proprio, veramente*, and *davvero,* but also *realmente* have a different meaning, and you should use them to say that the adjective applies really, and not necessarily in great measure.

*Addirittura* has still another meaning, as *perfino* and *nientemeno* you should use it to stress the fact that the adjective is applicable even if it could be not credible.

I advice you to check the adverbs on a dictionary and compare their meanings to better understand their use.

Comment: It's really a pity that this wealth of adverbs is ignored by many speakers who only rely on *assolutamente*.

Comment: Once source of my confusion was the English word 'really' - it can mean both 'very' *and* 'truly', so it translates both 'molto' and 'veramente'.

Comment: @egreg: You are absolutely right, this is why I absolutely avoided to add assolutamente to my list.